# Trouble on counting ActiveRecord instances in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, count

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to solve a issue counting ActiveRecord instances in an array.

---

I have this code

```
data = Account.where({:name => "Test_name", :city => "Test_city"}).limit(10)
```

The `data` debug is

```
#<Account:0x000001029d2da0>#<Account:0x000001029d2c60>#<Account:0x000001029d2bc0>#<Account:0x000001029d2b20>
```

The `data` inspecting is

```
"[#<Account name: \"Test_name\", city: \"Test_city\">, #<Account … >, #<Account id… >, …]"
```

*Doubt*: The *##<...>* should be something like `#<Account...>,#<Account...>,<...>` (note commas)?

---

If in my code I use the following

```
data_count = data.count
```

The `data_count` is

```
nil
```

---

**Why is it `nil`? How should I count accounts?**

---

- If I use `result = data.class` the debug of `result` is `nil`, but if I use `result = data.class`the debug is `"{\"inheritable_attributes\":{}}"`.
- If I use `Account.find_by_name("Test_name")` instead of `Account.where(...)` I get same results as above.

Comment: When I do exactly that on a model in one of my own projects I get the expected result from `count`. Please run your code in the Rails console and post your session from there exactly.

Comment: what are your attributes.......?

Comment: Attributes will be the problem.

Comment: But the '#<Account...>#<Account...><...>' (output of 'Account.where') should be something like '#<Account...>,#<Account...>,<...>' (note commas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get to the bottom of things, start the rails console with:

```
$ rails c
```

Given that Account is an ActiveRecord model, you should be able to do the following in the rails console:

```
> Account.all.count
=> 100
> Account.where(:status=>'active')
=> [ #<Account id: 1, name: "a1", ...>, #<Account id: 2, name: "a2", ...>, #<Account id: 3, name: "a3", ...>, ...]
```

I'm doing a lot of hand waving here with ... since I don't know your schema.  Replace the where condition with whatever works for your situation.  The returned value should look like an array with a list of all the rows in the database that match the condition.  BTW, an array is a list of element, and inspect (as well as the default display in the console) show element separated by commas.  I haven't used debug so I can't comment on what it should do.

You can verify that the returned value is an AREL, and should be able to do some other operations to verify things work as expected.

```
> Account.where(:status=>'active').class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
> Account.where(:status=>'active').size
=> 99
> Account.where(:status=>'active').count
=> 99
> Account.where(:status=>'active').limit(10).count
=> 10
```

If these work as expected in the console, there may be something in the view that is obscuring the correct behavior.  In that case you'll need to post the details of your view code.  If the strange behavior still occurs in the console, I would suggest posting the minimal parts of the actual model code that still exhibit the problem, along with the migration so we can see the schema.

Comment: I updated the question with the inspect. 'data.size' return 'nil. I don't use named scope.

Comment: By 'debug' I mean <=% debug data %> in a view file. The output of 'data_count = data.count.to_json' is "{\"inheritable_attributes\":{}}". Note that if I don't use 'to_json' I will get an nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having some problem in where condition.
Can you show the attributes value used in where clause.
For me its working fine:

```
 data = Account.where('id != 0').limit(10)
 data_count = data.count
```

Comment: @Ashish I have '{:id => 2, :email => "test_email@test.com"}'

Comment: If you have id in your where clause then it will return only one record :). Anyway try to print class of data by data.class

Comment: @Ashish If I do 'data.class' the debug of that is 'nil'.

Comment: @Ashish What do you mean? If you need some more info, ack me and I will update the question as well.

Comment: ok...Just run these lines from rails console and post all the outputs

Comment: @Ashish Output are the same in the question. I updated the question just adding the 'data.inspect' result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
data = Account.where("id = 2 and email = 'test_email@test.com'")
```